# Render a UIView to a UIImage larger than it is on screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, core-graphics

I would like to render a UIView into a UIImage. However, I would like to render it much larger than it is on screen, without pixilation.

At present I am using...

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0.0);
[self.pageViewController.view.layer renderInContext:context];
renderedViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I have tried...

```
self.pageViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4.0f, 4.0f);
```

This changes the size of the view but the original size is rendered before the view is scaled.

I have also tried...

```
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 4.0, 4.0);
```

but this just scales up the low resolution image giving a poor quality result.

Setting the...

```
UIView contentScaleFactor
```

hasn't helped me render the UIView any larger either.

Comment: did you even find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try This  you will get 2x size image of view if device supports retina

```
  - (UIImage *)imageOfView:(UIView *)view
{

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    }

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```